# Recurrence relation for 2nCn

Tags: recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

Does there exist an easy to compute (by hand) recurrence relation for the central column of pascals triangle?

I'm trying to avoid factorials.

A recurrence for {1, 2, 6, 20, 70, 252... }
Thanks in advance, Ben

Comment: They satisfy the recurrence $$a_{n+1}= \frac{4n+2}{n+1}a_n$$

see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sequence $A000984$ in $OEIS$. You will find a lot of informations about it and, in particular,
$$n a_n+2(1-2n)a_{n-1}=0 \qquad \text{with} \qquad a_0=1$$

**Edit**

As I wrote in comments, in the $OEIS$ page, Gerry Martens gave in 2011 the nice
$$a_n=\frac{ (-4)^n \sqrt{\pi }}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right) \Gamma (n+1)}$$ If you want an approximation which is quite accurate (using Stirling approximation and Padé approximants for making the series more compact)
$$\log(a_n)\simeq 2\log(2)n-\log(\sqrt{\pi n})-\frac{5 n \left(5208 n^2+4121\right)}{6 \left(34720 n^4+28920 n^2+771\right)}$$ which is equivalent to an $O\left(\frac{1}{n^9}\right)$ series expansion.

For example, for $a_{10}$ the result is $184756.00000013$.

Comment: Thanks Claude! I'll have to try OEIS more often. Didn't think of that!

Comment: @BenCrossley. It is an incredible source of information. I use it very often (as many eople) in particular for asymptotics, codes and so on. Cheers.

Comment: Do you know of a way to turn this recurrence into one without divisions? Or into one dependant on multiple previous terms?

Comment: @BenCrossley. If you look at the page in OEIS, you will find $$a_n=\frac{ (-4)^n \sqrt{\pi }}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right) \Gamma (n+1)}$$ given by Gerry Martens in 2011

Comment: That has divisions in it too!
No fractions at all. I couldn't see one on the OEIS page.